# When install external python packages global, when local? pip or system package-manager?

Tags: python, pip, global, package, local

I'm confused about the possibilities of installing external python packages:

1. install package local with `pip` into `/home/chris/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages`
   `$ pip install --user packagename`
2. install package global with `pip` into `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages`
   (superuser permission required)
   `$ pip install packagename`
3. install package global with `zypper` into `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages`
   (superuser permission required)
   `$ zypper install packagename`

I use OpenSuse with package-manager `zypper` and have access to user root.

What I (think to) know about `pip` is that:
- `pip` just downloads the latest version.
- For installed packages won't be checked if newer versions are available.
- Own packages can be installed in a virtual env.
- Takes more time to download and install than `zypper`.
- Local or global installation possible.

The package-manager of my system:
- Does download and installation faster.
- Installs the package only globally.

My question is when and why should I do the installation: `pip` (local, global) or with `zypper`?
I've read a lot about this issue but could not answer this question clearly...

Comment: Pls ignore this question: I was not aware of using virtual-environments back in 2017. I am using `venv` since years that solved this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The stuff under /usr/lib is system packages considered part of the OS. It's likely/possible that OS scripts and services will have dependencies on these components. I'd recommend not touching these yourself, or really using or depending on them for user scripts either as this will make your app OS or even OS version dependent. Use these if writing scripts that run at system level such as doing maintenance or admin tasks, although I'd seriously consider even these using...

Stuff under /usr/local/lib is installed locally for use by any user. System scripts and such won't depend on these (I don't know SuSE myself though), but other user's scripts might well do, so that needs to be borne in mind when making changes here. It's a shared resource. If your writing scripts that other users might need to run, develop against this to ensure they will have access to all required dependencies.

Stuff in your home directory is all yours, so do as thou wilt. Use this if you're writing something just for yourself and especially if you might need the scripts to be portable to other boxes/OSes.

There might well be other options that make sense, such as if you're part of a team developing application software, in which case install your team's base dev packages in a shared location but perhaps not /usr/local.

In terms of using zypper or pip, I'd suggest using zypper to update /usr/lib for sure as it's the specific tool for OS configuration update. Probably same goes for /usr/local/lib too as that's really part of the 'system' but it's really up to you and which method might make most sense e.g. if you needed to replicate the config an another host. For stuff in your homedir it's up to you but if you decide to move to a new host on a new OS, pip will still be available and so that environment will be easier to recreate.